# Using an SQL Query to skip or run a code in ArcPy/ Python

Tags: arcpy, python, sql, if-statement

Using ArcMap 10.4 and Python I am trying to run a code (arcpy.ExportReport) on a bunch of different frequency tables. Which I have completed the only problem is that if I have a table that does not match my definition query the code does not run and will not export the report.

Basically, how do I skip the code from running when the definition query parameters are not met.

Code Block:

```
            if:
               report_definition_query =SQL_NAME2arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(lyr,Template,PDF,"DEFINITION_QUERY",report_definitonn_query =SQL_NAME2)

           else:print "Blank Report"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working just add NAME_OF_ERROR you receive (for ex. ValueError)

```
            try:
               report_definition_query =SQL_NAME2arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(lyr,Template,PDF,"DEFINITION_QUERY",report_definitonn_query =SQL_NAME2)

           except NAME_OF_ERROR:print "Blank Report"
```